# How to get Middle record in each group using Linq

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework-6, linq-to-entities

Get Middle record in each group using Linq. My code and there is an error on skip:

[image]

```
    var v = from a in db.SJadwal_Produksi
                join b in db.SJenis_Masakan on a.ID_Masakan equals b.ID_Masakan
                join c in db.LAB_ORLAP_Retained on a.PriKey equals c.FK_KodeProduksi into ps
                from c in ps.DefaultIfEmpty()
                where (DbFunctions.TruncateTime(a.Tanggal_Masakan.Value) == DbFunctions.TruncateTime(F00))
                group new { a, b, c } by new { a.Tanggal_Masakan, a.ID_Masakan } into g
                select new
                {
                    nomor = g.OrderBy(n=>n.a.N_Masakan).Skip((g.Count()/2)-(g.Count()%2==0?1:0)).FirstOrDefault().a.N_Masakan,
                };
```

Comment: What is it? EF6, EF Core?

Comment: I'm using EF 6 in my project

Comment: I think you can put the `OrderBy()` method into the query directly above the `select` as an `order by` statement. That should simplify your `nomor` statement. Also, couldn't you do this as a second linked query `var w = from r in v`? That might make the intent of your query easier to understand from a maintenance perspective.

Comment: [Please don't post code or exceptions as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: Unfortunately it is not possible by EF. You can do that only on client-side. Or rewrite your query using pure SQL and Window Functions.